# Django SearchVector using icontains

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to search for a list of values in multiple columns in postgres (via django). I was able to use SearchQuery and SearchVector and this works great if one of the search values matches a full word. I was hoping to use icontains so that partial strings could also be used in the search. Is this possible and if so could someone point me in the right direction. Here is an example of my approach below.

Example Data:

```
Superhero.objects.create(
    superhero='Batman',
    publisher='DC Comics', 
    alter_ego='Bruce Wayne',
)
Superhero.objects.create(
    superhero='Hulk',
    publisher='Marvel Comics',
    alter_ego='Bruce Banner',
)
```

Django filter:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchVector

query = SearchQuery('man') | SearchQuery('Bruce') 
vector = SearchVector('superhero', 'alter_ego', 'publisher')
queryset = queryset.annotate(search=vector).filter(search=query)
```

This would return the Hulk record but I am hoping I can somehow use like 'icontains' so that when searching for 'man' the Batman record would also be returned. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So SearchQuery and SearchVector are a part of Django's Full Text searching functionality and it doesnt look like you can achieve what I was wanting to do with these functions. I have taken a different approach thanks to Julian Phalip's approach here.. https://www.julienphalip.com/blog/adding-search-to-a-django-site-in-a-snap/

Answer (score 6):

You can apply `icontains` to the filter like:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(search=vector).filter(search__icontains=query)
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the search term has a whitespace.