# Django SearchVector doesn't work with search query containing whitespace

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-3, django-searchvector

I have a `name` field on which I am trying to annotate with a SearchVector. It works fine if I don't add a whitespace in search string but returns empty list if I add a whitespace.
Same string works just fine with regular `filter` queryset.

```py
>>> r = Resource.objects.filter(name__icontains='LAKSHMI NURSING')
>>> r
<QuerySet [<Resource: LAKSHMI NURSING HOME>]>
>>>
```

Using Search vector without a white-space string

```py
>>> r = Resource.objects.annotate(
...             search=SearchVector('name', 'type')
...             ).filter(search__icontains='LAKSHMI')
>>> r
<QuerySet [<Resource: LAKSHMI NURSING HOME>]>
>>>
```

With White-space:

```py
>>> r = Resource.objects.annotate(
...             search=SearchVector('name', 'type')
...             ).filter(search__icontains='LAKSHMI NURSING')
>>> r
<QuerySet []>
>>>
```

Comment: Similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867384/django-searchvector-using-icontains)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are the results if you try :

```
r = Resource.objects.annotate(
...             search=SearchVector('name', 'type')
...             ).filter(search='LAKSHMI NURSING')
```

without icontains ?
In the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector), I do not see example with `search__icontains`.

Another option could be to use `SearchQuery` :

```
    from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery
    queryset = queryset.annotate(
        search=SearchVector(*args)
    ).filter(search=SearchQuery(search_text))
```

Comment: That worked, actually both of them. Thanks!