# Using icontains for search queries with spaces in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I made simple search through my site, which is searching through several models within app. It worked fine until i realized that it can't search queries with spaces. Is there any option to search with spaces?

Model:

```
class Event(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Object

```
Event.objects.create(
   name="Test query event",
   description="Test Description"
)
```

Query itself:

```
query = "test query"
Event.objects.all().annotate(search=SearchVector("name")).filter(search__icontains=query)
```

I'm using latest versions of Django+DRF+django-filters, but it's possible to add other packages to project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django SearchVector using icontains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867384/django-searchvector-using-icontains)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide some more information on what is happening and what your search term(s) look like?

After re-reading this I think you may be trying to search for partial words, but your example is giving full words.  If your example is accurate, then you don't need to do anything:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchVector

Event.objects.create(name="test query")
Event.objects.create(name="tESt qUEry")
Event.objects.create(name="test not a query")
Event.objects.create(name="ignore this")

qs = Event.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector("name"))

qs.filter(search="test query")
# <QuerySet [Event('test query'), Event('tESt qUEry'), Event('test not a query')]>

# Use a SearchQuery to search for them together:

qs.filter(search=SearchQuery("test query", search_type="phrase"))
# <QuerySet [Event('test query'), Event('tESt qUEry')]>
```

Comment: It is working, but i'd like to search not only with full words - queries like "test que" or "test q" should return something.

I saw another solution with Q objects, but not sure if it's optimal solution

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use this query.
`qs = Event.objects.filter(name__icontains="test q")`
If you have multiple words to search then you can use Q like this.

```
qs = Event.objects.filter(
Q(name__icontains="test q")| Q(name__icontains="test queue")
)
```